# avahi-autoipd removing static interface

Tags: networking, dhcp, avahi

I am having some trouble with the AVAHI daemon. I am not using networkmanager, instead just configuring /etc/network/interfaces. I am configuring two interfaces for the ethernet adapter:

- one using DHCP
- one with a static IP

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

auto eno1:0
allow-hotplug eno1:0
iface eno1:0 inet static
    address 192.168.133.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Until recently I had no problems with this setup, but lately I am having a problem. If after some time the DHCP connection does not get a DHCP IP assignation, a new interface eno1:avahi gets created with an autoassigned IP, and the static ip interface eno1:0 gets removed.

I've been looking to remove avahi-autoipd but I only can find solutions that require removing avahi-server, and I need avahi-server installed.

How can I disable avahi-autoipd, or prevent it from disabling the `eno1:0` interface?